# Site collection REST API

Tags: site-collection, listdata.svc, rest

I would like to know how to access a list of sites with the ListData.svc REST API.

Thanks.

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: If you are using SP 2013, then use Alex's suggestion. If you are using SP 2010 you will need to use the JavaScript Client Object Model to get this information.

Comment: 2010 and REST is a **MUST**

Answer (score 2):

The REST interface uses flexible URL conventions for querying data, which enable you to filter, sort and **select information from SharePoint Foundation lists** directly from the browser.

The ListData.svc is for getting information from lists and libaries not for getting a list of sites.

Link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I know, but, is there a **list** containing the sites. `SPList` with `SPListItem` about sites.

Comment: Not that I know

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such list.

Answer (score 0):

Webs will get you all the sites directly beneath the site, but not their children according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246370%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/webs
```

Comment: _api and `ListData.svc` are ***not*** the same thing.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I momentarily mixed up client.svc and listdata.svc.  I'll leave the answer in case anyone needs it for 2013, but feel free to downvote it as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No problem. We have a hard enough time getting people to upvote anything around here...